# C#- Load paged GridView on page where rows(Date) is most recent

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sorting, gridview

I have a grid view which contains past, present and future dates. When the page loads. How can I set it to show starting from date today or more recent and still having access with the past and future dates?

I have this on my .aspx file

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" ItemType="XXXXX.Models.YYYYY" DataKeyNames="YYYYYID"
            SelectMethod="YYYYYGrid_GetData" UpdateMethod="YYYYYGrid_UpdateItem"
             AutoGenerateColumns="false" AllowSorting="true" AllowPaging="true" 

    ...

    <Columns>

        ...

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Date" SortExpression="YYYYYDateTime">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label Text="<%# Item.YYYYYDateTime.Value.ToShortDateString()%>"
                    runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        ...

    </Columns>

    ...

</asp:GridView>
```

Here's the code to Get data

```
public IQueryable<YYYYY> YYYYYGrid_GetData([Control] YYYYY._SSSSS? displaySSSSS)
    {
        XXXXXContext db = new XXXXXContext();
        int id = int.Parse(Session["DDDDDID"].ToString());
        var query = db.YYYYY.Where(p => p.DDDDDID == id).Include(p => p.PPPPP);

        if (displaySSSSS != null)
        {
            query = query.Where(s => s.SSSSS == displaySSSSS);
        }

        return query;
    }
```

Example target output:

```
Data from Database:
-----------------
Date     |  Data
03/01/15 |  AA
03/02/15 |  BB
04/01/16 |  CC
04/03/16 |  DD
04/05/16 |  EE

Gridview on Page load:
-----------------
Date     |  Data
04/03/16 |  DD     <-- eg. date today
04/05/16 |  EE
          page 2

Navigate gridview to page 1 to show past dates:
---------------
Date     |  Data
03/01/15 |  AA
03/02/15 |  BB
04/01/16 |  CC
```

Comment: Please post your code in the question.

Comment: show us your code and where are you stuck? Is your GridView bind with Database data or these are dynamic data you are binding?

Comment: @BikashSinghMaharjan posted it, thanks.

Comment: @RojalinSahoo it is bounded to a database. posted my code, thanks!

Comment: You could fetch data using order by desc or asc , then bind that to gridview

Comment: @RojalinSahoo my goal is when the page loads, the first data in the grid view is the date today, and so on. but I still want my past dates to be accessible. I'll include an example in my post. thank you!

Comment: You could use the select statement as `Select * from tablename order by date_field desc `. It will yield output with ordering as today's date first then previous date and save that in datatable then bind that with Gridview. Note that you have todays date in database.

Comment: Colud I have a look on your SelectMethod?